# Clean source code parse website with jsoup

Tags: java, string, jsoup

When analyzed by java jsoup site, I want to remove the `/>` in each `img` tag.

Source:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">ABC</a> 
    <a href="#"><img src="#"/></a>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Result:

```
<div>
    <a href="#">ABC</a> 
    <a href="#"><img src="#"></a>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: And what have you done so far?

Comment: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/

Comment: That is the default behavior in jsoup anyway ( see http://try.jsoup.org/~eYysnADkqheNuQ4uVBCPoAGPybA), so what is the specific problem?

Comment: Hi I wanted to ask how I can remove "/>" in img.because I use the content for bloggers, bloggers asked to remove "/>" to be able to display accurate results

Comment: You can use `Jsoup.parse(yourHtmlString).html()` method but this will come along  with html body.

Answer (score 0):

Try `html()` method

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s="<div>\n" +
                "    <a href=\"#\">ABC</a> \n" +
                "    <a href=\"#\"><img src=\"#\"/></a>\n" +
                "    <br/>\n" +
                "</div>";
        System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(s).html());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div> 
   <a href="#">ABC</a> 
   <a href="#"><img src="#"></a> 
   <br> 
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```